# How to get the 'speed' of the water in the 3. sink?

Tags: logic

We have 3 sinks, from which water flows in a tank.
A 30degree one fills the tank in 4min. A 100 degree one fills the tank in 6min, and the average temperature of the water is 60 degree when the tank is full.
The question is, how fast does the 3. sink with 70 degree of water fill the tank alone?

Answer (score 2):

A fills the tank at $\frac {1}{4} \frac {\text{tank}}{\text{min}}$

B fills the tank at $\frac {1}{6} \frac {\text{tank}}{\text{min}}$

C fills the tank at $\frac {1}{x} \frac {\text{tank}}{\text{min}}$

The the total flow into the tank in 1 minute is $\frac {1}{4} + \frac {1}{6} + \frac {1}{x}$

$\frac {1}{4} 30^\circ + \frac {1}{6} 100^\circ  + \frac {1}{x}70^{\circ} = (\frac {1}{4} + \frac {1}{6} + \frac {1}{x})60^{\circ}$

lets multiply trough by $24x$

$180x + 400x  + 1680 = (6x + 4x + 24)60\\
20x = 240\\
x = 12$

Comment: Just one more question, if I would add some 0 degree water before opening the tanks, and the average temperate would be 40, how could I calculate the amount of water with 0 degree? Since multiply with 0 degree would give 0 anyways... So I can't make the same equation there.